# header and footer in letter class newlfm

Tags: header-footer, newlfm

I am trying to write letters using newlfm. The first page is fine but on subsequent pages it puts bars for the header and footer but doesn't include the address, logos etc. that appear on the first page. I'd prefer subsequent pages to be blank except for my text.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[stdletter,11pt]{newlfm} 

\addrfromskipbefore{10pt}
\unprbottom{1cm}

\newsavebox{\CortlandLogo} 
\sbox{
\CortlandLogo}{\parbox[t]{1.75in}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,ext=.pdf]{CortlandLogo}}
}

\newsavebox{\PhysDept}
\sbox{
\PhysDept}{\parbox[t]{5cm}{\sf \Large Physics Department}
}


\Rheader{\usebox{\CortlandLogo}}
\Lheader{\usebox{\PhysDept}}

\newsavebox{\Footertext} 
\sbox{\Footertext}{
\begin{minipage}[c]{15cm}
\begin{center}
\sf Bowers Hall, Room 342,  P.O. Box 2000, Cortland, NY 13045-0900, United States\\
Phone: (607) 753-2821  Fax: (607) 753-2927
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
}  
\Cfooter{\usebox{\Footertext}}

\namefrom{Dr. Andrew Carmichael} 
\addrfrom{\parbox{2.5in}{Dr. Andrew Carmichael\\ Office: Bowers 133\\ Phone: 607 753-5697 }} 

\begin{document} 
\closeline{Yours faithfully,} 

\begin{newlfm} 
{\bf Re: BLAH BLAH}

\vspace{1cm}

TEXT TEXT BLAH BLAH TEXT WHEN THERE'S ENOUGH TEXT HERE IT GOES OVER TO TWO PAGES AND THERE THE TROUBLE STARTS

\end{newlfm} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: You can format code as code by indenting it by 4 spaces (easy way: highlight the code and press '{}' button). You can hit the 'edit' button to see how I've formatted the code in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class uses the page style `othhead` for pages from the second page on; so you can simply `\let` this page style to be the `empty` page style; this can be done using

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@othhead\ps@empty
\makeatother
```

A complete example using a simplified version of your code:

```
\documentclass[stdletter,11pt]{newlfm} 

\makeatletter
\let\ps@othhead\ps@empty
\makeatother

\Rheader{Right}
\Lheader{Left}
\Cfooter{Center}

\namefrom{Dr. Andrew Carmichael} 
\addrfrom{\parbox{2.5in}{Dr. Andrew Carmichael\\ Office: Bowers 133\\ Phone: 607 753-5697 }} 

\begin{document} 

\closeline{Yours faithfully,} 
\begin{newlfm} 

text

\newpage

Some other text
\end{newlfm} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks. However, I now have the problem that the text in the footer on page 1 (which has two lines) grazes the very bottom of the page. Can I increase the space for the footer?

Comment: Actually got it with \unprbottom{1cm}. Thank you for your help. You're a genius.

Comment: How do you do this so that the subsequent pages have the same header as the first page?