# header and footer in all pages of letter class newlfm

Tags: header-footer, newlfm

Following [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161558/header-and-footer-in-letter-class-newlfm), I would just want to have the footer in every page of the document, but I don't find a way... besides, could I put it a little bit up, without changing the bottom margin? Thanks!

Would it be possible as well to remove the ":" after Telephone and E-mail??

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm}



%%%HORIZONTAL LINES
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91052/remove-header-and-footer-lines-in-newlfm
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\ps@ltrhead}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\g@addto@macro{\ps@othhead}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{lastpage}

\Lfooter{John Smith\hspace{1em}-\hspace{1em}{\small john@smith.com}\hspace{5em}\textit{Cover Letter}}
\Rfooter{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}



\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.75in}{\vspace{0.5in}
\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{logo.png}}} % Company/institution logo at the top left of the page
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}

\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}

\lthUiuc
\namefrom{John Smith}

\addrfrom{
\today\\[12pt]
123 Broadway \\
City, State 12345
}

\phonefrom{(000) 111-1111}

\emailfrom{john@smith.com}

\greetto{Dear Mrs. Smith,}
\closeline{Sincerely yours,}

\nameto{Mrs. Jane Smith}

\addrto{
Recruitment Officer \\
The Corporation \\
123 Pleasant Lane \\
City, State 12345
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

\lipsum
\lipsum
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy implementation of your cover letter, completely void of [`newlfm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm). As such, it is completely customizable to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Page geometry
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  margin=0.5in,% Equal margin of 0.5in from all four sides
  includefoot% Include only the footer in the margin calculations, since you don't have a header
}

% Header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}% Page style will be fancy
\fancyhf{}% Clear headers and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule (default)
\fancyfoot[L]{John Smith \quad - \quad \href{mailto:john@smith.com}{{\small john@smith.com}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textit{Cover Letter}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx,lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus 0.1\baselineskip minus 0.1\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}% Logo

\bigskip

\null\hfill% FROM details
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \today \\[\normalbaselineskip]
  123 Broadway \\
  City, State 12345 \\
  Telephone (000) 111-1111 \\
  Email \href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

% TO details
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  Mrs.\ Jane Smith \\
  Recruitment Officer \\
  The Corporation \\
  123 Pleasant Lane \\
  City, State 12345
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Dear Mrs.\ Smith,

\bigskip

\lipsum[1-10]% You letter

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  Sincerely yours, \\[5\normalbaselineskip]
  John Smith
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Werner! I am going to accept this answer, though it doesn't explicitly address the question, but it covers all the problems I listed, and allows me to customize many other things (like adding a 2nd phone number and a Skype contact)! Thanks again!

Comment: @DaniCee: I've always been a proponent of using the default document classes for letters, since the other provide a strange interface for me. In general, document classes typically provide a restrictive view on a specific document type, while packages are meant to extend the functionality. Using a very basic class (like `article`) and extending it with packages (like in my example) is therefore very easy customizable.

Answer (score 1):

This satisfies some of your desiderata. In particular, it uses the footer on all pages.

I'm not certain how exactly you want the footer moved up without changing the bottom margin. If 'bottom margin' is intended to include the footer, obviously you cannot move the footer up without changing it. So I assume you mean 'bottom margin' as the bottom of the last line of the body of the letter on the page. But then I don't see how the footer can move up without changing the margin. Not, at least, without making things look awful. So I've not attempted this here.

Finally, having taken a look at the code of the class, personally I would learn to live with the colons. However, you may feel differently if you dislike them strongly enough. (The documented code is not included in the manual I have and the code itself contains precious little by way of commentary. Eventually, I gave up trying to figure out which command might be responsible for the colons. However, I suspect it is buried fairly deep so that you would have to duplicate a fair chunk of code in your preamble. Obviously that's doable but I would not personally think it worth it. I could, however, been entirely misguided in my suspicions.)

So, in the end, I've only really changed one thing:

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\ps@ltrhead}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\g@addto@macro{\ps@othhead}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage,calc}

\newsavebox{\Ltlfoot}
\sbox{\Ltlfoot}{John Smith\hspace{1em}-\hspace{1em}{\small john@smith.com}\hspace{5em}\textit{Cover Letter}}
\newlength{\myfootheight}
\settoheight{\myfootheight}{\usebox{\Ltlfoot}}

\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.75in}{\vspace{0.5in}
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}}}
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{%
  \Lfooter{\usebox{\Ltlfoot}}%
  \Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}
\Rfooter{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfooter{\usebox{\Ltlfoot}}
\rfooter{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt, minfoot=\myfootheight}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}

\lthUiuc
\namefrom{John Smith}

\addrfrom{
  \today\\[12pt]
  123 Broadway \\
  City, State 12345
}

\phonefrom{(000) 111-1111}

\emailfrom{john@smith.com}

\greetto{Dear Mrs. Smith,}
\closeline{Sincerely yours,}

\nameto{Mrs. Jane Smith}

\addrto{
  Recruitment Officer \\
  The Corporation \\
  123 Pleasant Lane \\
  City, State 12345
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{newlfm}

    \lipsum[1-10]

  \end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

[image: More footers]

Comment: Thanks @cfr, I will learn to live with the ":".

I just have a couple of little problems.

1-Why does the footer on the 2nd page appear noticeably lower than in the first?

2-I wanted to add \href{mailto:john@smith.com}{{\small john@smith.com}} in the footer, something that I could do before, but now I get the error Undefined control sequence.

Comment: @DaniCee Good question. It seems that the class does not take account of the footer on non-letterhead pages. At least, that's my guess. There is something odd going on. If you load the `layout` class and use the commands `\layout` and `\layout*`, things look really messy in the second case (which tries to recompute the dimensions before displaying the layout).

Comment: @DaniCee It seems that setting the length of `minfoot` to a suitable value gets the footers aligned. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @cfr, this is some really nice information, and it tackles my main problem explicitly, using newlfm. However, I am going to accept the answer below as it covers all my problems and allows me to customize many other things... Thanks!